# What am I doing Wrong when flagging?

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268706/plane-is-now-a-circle?noredirect=1#comment459767_268706) that's obviously lacking in details and clarity before the comments in that post came in saying the same thing that it was lacking in details. But it got declined without any comments or reason. I did leave a comment trying to guess the issue but that doesn't mean the issue is clear so I should be able to flag it or not?

[image]

But,

**According to [What is Flagging](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)**

[image]

Can anyone fill me in? Is it discouraged to flag posts for lack of details and clarity or have the rules changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, in this case I dismissed you flag for three reasons:

1. The main one being that despite the obvious lack of detail a probable cause of the issue can be deduced from the sparse details. You in fact seem to have discovered it as confirmed by Lisa's comment
2. Lisa is a new user and I didn't want to immediately close her question to give her an opportunity to improve it. Close questions are usually accused of being hostile to new users and don't encourage improvement. Also as moderators our vote is binding, so if we were to take any action it would have taken effect immediately bypassing the community voting process.
3. Although flagging is possible and a a valid way for calling attention, for these basic cases were no particular moderator attention is required we prefer you use regular close votes system, were all users can help with review.

Flagging should generally be reserved for more serious offenses, rude behavior or something that requires more immediate attention or special care.

For regular maintenance and reviewing voting to close creates less overhead because all other users with enough reputation to enter review queues have the ability to help, thus sharing some of the load of site maintenance with the community.

Also see

- [Help about Flags](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) and
- [Help about declined flags](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/declined-flags)

Comment: thanks for the reaponse! fair enough. but it would be awesome if that was included in the documentation :)

Comment: No problem, thanks for the feedback. I don't think we as moderators have any permission to edit most documentation unfortunately

Comment: As for the second bullet point: as a moderator you can indicate a flag as helpful without it having any consequence for the user contribution that was flagged. If,as you state, a flag is appropriate, it should be considered as such (I'm having a lot of flags declined, and am confused about this as well).

Comment: It's even more annoying when a flag was declined but an action was nonetheless taken to have the desired effect (like an answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150686/eevee-transparent-glass-on-transparent-background/150772#150772)). While not closing questions might retain new users, this modus operandi does demotivate users new to this site but familiar with others on the network from contributing to the quality of the site.

Comment: @Joachim the goal is not to avoid closing the question entirely, just to delay it long enough to create a window of opportunity for the user to improve them. If you ever find a low quality post or a flag that was denied and you don't know why, please do open a meta post or ping someone at chat to clarify. Some times motivations are not entirely clear, or moderators inadvertently miss something. Discussion here may also change our minds